# UWP:- How to update MediaStreamSample.Timestamp in Unmanaged without having to create Media stream sample again and again

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, webrtc

I've been getting I420 video frames from mixed reality webrtc at 30 fps. I'm using the following code to create the media samples and copy the frame from webrtc to this Media sample and attach it to the sample generated from the MediaStreamSource.SampleRequested event. But the rendering experience is not looking good with more media players in the UWP app with Media stream sample created every time.

It has been said that the Media Stream sample timestamp can be updated in unmanaged code without the need to create a new media stream sample with the updated timestamp thereby saving time spent by GC. But I'm not sure how. Can some one throw some light on how can I achieve this in unmanaged code?

```
public class StreamSamplePool
{         
      /// <summary>
      /// Queue of buffers in use by a sample.
      /// </summary>
      /// <remarks>
      /// Newly used buffers are added on the back of the queue, and removed
        /// from the front once the <see cref="Windows.Media.Core.MediaStreamSample.Processed"/>
        /// signal is fired. Because some users report out-of-order or missing
        /// calls, all earlier buffers are also removed, so order of the buffers
        /// in the queue reflects the chronology and matters.
        /// </remarks>

        Queue<Buffer> _usedBuffers;

        /// <summary>
        /// Stack of free buffers available for recycling by a new sample.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Since buffer resize shall correspond to video resize and thus be infrequent,
        /// favor reusing the last released buffer, which is most likely to have the same
        /// capacity as the new frame, by using a stack.
        /// </remarks>
        Stack<Buffer> _freeBuffers;

        /// <summary>
        /// Construct a new pool of buffers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="capacity">Initial capacity of both the used and free collections of buffers</param>
        public StreamSamplePool(int capacity)
        {
            this._usedBuffers = new Queue<Buffer>(capacity);
            this._freeBuffers = new Stack<Buffer>(capacity);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a sample from the pool which has a buffer with a given capacity
        /// and with the associated timestamp.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="byteSize">The exact size in bytes that the sample buffer needs to accomodate.</param>
        /// <param name="timestamp">The sample presentation timestamp.</param>
        /// <returns>The newly created sample</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The returned sample's buffer has a <see cref="Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer.Length"/> property
        /// set to the input <see cref="byteSize"/>. This is required to be set before creating the sample,
        /// and should not be modified once the sample was created.
        /// </remarks>
        public MediaStreamSample Pop(uint byteSize, System.TimeSpan timestamp)
        {
            Buffer buffer;
            lock (this)
            {
                if (_freeBuffers.Count > 0)
                {
                    buffer = _freeBuffers.Pop();
                    if (buffer.Capacity < byteSize)
                    {
                        buffer = new Buffer(byteSize);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    buffer = new Buffer(byteSize);
                }
                _usedBuffers.Enqueue(buffer);

                // This must be set before calling CreateFromBuffer() below otherwise
                // the Media Foundation pipeline throws an exception.
                buffer.Length = byteSize;
            }

            // Because the managed wrapper does not allow modifying the timestamp,
            // need to recreate the sample each time with the correct timestamp.
            var sample = MediaStreamSample.CreateFromBuffer(buffer, timestamp);
            sample.Processed += OnSampleProcessed;
            return sample;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Callback fired by MediaFoundation when a <see cref="Windows.Media.Core.MediaStreamSample"/>
        /// has been processed by the pipeline and its buffer can be reused.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sample">The sample which has been processed.</param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        private void OnSampleProcessed(MediaStreamSample sample, object args)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                // This does a linear search from front, which generally finds
                // the first object (oldest) or at worse one very close to front,
                // so is optimal anyway.
                // Remove this sample and all earlier ones too. Some users report that
                // the Processed event is not always reported for earlier samples, which
                // would result in memory leaks. This may be due to out-of-order reporting.
                while (_usedBuffers.TryDequeue(out Buffer buffer))
                {
                    // Save the buffer for later reuse
                    _freeBuffers.Push(buffer);

                    if (buffer == sample.Buffer)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So this is the code you are using right? Could you please tell me why you want to change the timestamp?

Comment: so basically, whenever I’m getting a new I420 video frame, I thought of using the already created media stream sample by updating the underlying sample buffer alone with time stamp. I need to update the time stamp to have the media sample with the updated buffer rendered in media player. Since i don’t have that option now, I’m creating a new media stream sample with new time stamp every time to have it rendered by media player. This is causing rendering delays with more media players in the UI and GC is taking a hit as far I understand.

Comment: Also I understand the rationale behind not exposing the time stamp property to be updated in managed code as the underlying buffer could still be in use by the media foundation pipeline. But I’m not sure how can I update this implementation alone to unmanaged to update timestamp and gaining access to low level buffer. I tried with IMFSample (win32 api) in c++ winrt. but it is turning out to reimplement the entire rendering implementation and moving to mfplay.h (which is not consumable in c++/winrt). Hence, looking out for a solution how the above implementation can be converted to unmanaged.

Answer (score 0):

I've consulted the team about this. I got a response from one of the Media SMEs. So the answer is that unfortunately there is no way to achieve what you are trying to do, especially since the Timestamp property is read-only. What you are doing is as optimal as you'll get and you can't make it better with a MediaStreamSample.